# BEGIN_MSG_MAP parameter

Tags: c++, winapi, com, atl

Can we have BEGIN_MSG_MAP takes parameter as some other class?
Like in example below BEGIN_MSG_MAP in CMyEmbeddedWnd can have
CMainWindow as parameter?I have read that BEGIN_MSG_MAP parameter
should be the class name in which it is written.So is something like below possible and what can happen if we write code like below?

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CBaseEmbeddedWnd: public CComControl<CBaseEmbeddedWnd>,
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>
{
};

class CMyEmbeddedWnd: public CBaseEmbeddedWnd
{
public:
    CMyEmbeddedWnd();
    virtual ~CMyEmbeddedWnd();

    // window message map    
    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMainWindow)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_MESSAGE, OnMessage)
        CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CBaseEmbeddedWnd)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    // public functions
    HRESULT Init(CMainWindow* pWndParent);

    // message handlers
    LRESULT OnMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled);

protected:
    CMainWindow* m_pWndParent;
};

class CMainWindow: public CWindowImpl<CMainWindow>
{
public:
    // constructor and destructor
    CMainWindow();
    ~CMainWindow(){}

    // window message map    
    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMainWindow)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CREATE, OnCreate)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_DESTROY, OnDestroy)
    END_MSG_MAP()
    ...

private:
    CComObject<CMyEmbeddedWnd>* m_pwndEmbedded;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking for. What is your ultimate goal? What is the architectural problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: BEGIN_MSG_MAP is just a macro, you can get to the source using Go to Definition (F12). You'll see what it actually does and you can redefine a similar one that would suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you don't explain the ultimate goal, the answer is "No". The parameter is supposed to allow internal upcasting to your class and is not suitable for forwarding between classes. In the case of this particular macro, the parameter is ignored at all. To pass message handling between classes you have other macros to use: `ALT_MSG_MAP`, [`CHAIN_MSG_MAP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s763e097%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), `CHAIN_MSG_MAP_MEMBER` etc.